# Fancybox galleries firs image launcher

Tags: jquery, fancybox, gallery, fancybox-2

I have some galleries on page. First image is launcher, other images have display:none.

```
<?php if ($i == 1): ?>
   <a class="fancyboxLauncher" rel="group1" href="URL"><img src="URL"></a>
<?php else: ?>
   <div class="display_none">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="URL"><img src="URL"></a>
      <a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="URL"><img src="URL"></a>   
   </div>                   
<?php endif; ?>
```

// I have some galleries (group1, group2, group3 ...etc)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancyboxLauncher").on("click", function(){
    $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger("click");
    return false;
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox")
    .fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function() {
            this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
        }
    });             
</script>
```

This code start only first gallery on page. How to launch any gallery?

I'm sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have set different galleries using a different `rel` attribute ...

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" ...
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" ...

<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" ...
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" ...
```

... etc.

You could set different launchers for each gallery using the same *class* like :

```
<a class="fancyboxLauncher" data-group="gallery1" href="URL">Gallery 1 launcher</a>
<a class="fancyboxLauncher" data-group="gallery2" href="URL">Gallery 2 launcher</a>
```

**Notice** that the launchers don't need to have the same `rel` attribute as the images on each gallery since they are, well, just launchers (they may have the same thumbnail as the first image of the gallery though.) Also **notice** that we have set a `data-group` attribute, which indicates what gallery each launcher is targeting to.

Then you could use this code for both, the launchers and fancybox :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancyboxLauncher").on("click", function () {
        var thisGroup = $(this).data("group");
        $(".fancybox[rel=" + thisGroup + "]").eq(0).trigger("click");
        return false;
    });
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function () {
            this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
        }
    });
}); // ready
</script>
```

**Notice** that both scripts are wrapped inside the same `.ready()` method.

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zLUgD/)</kbd>

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for describing solutions.